# The initial setup with DbFit not working

Tags: mysql, database, testing, fitnesse, dbfit

I am new to DbFit and Fitnesse using Version 2.0.0-RC5. I have followed the setup instructions exactly as followed on the github tutorial. I have tried many different ways to get it working but end up getting errors.

The tutorial: http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/getting-started.html

Heres what HelloWorldTest looks like:

```
  !path lib/*.jar

  !|dbfit.MySqlTest|

  !|Connect|localhost|root|root|dbfit|

  !|Query| select 'test' as x|
  |x|
  |test|
```

When I run the test I am getting:

```
  Could not find fixture: dbfit.MySqlTest
  Could not find fixture: Connect
  Could not find fixture: Query
```

I have looked far and wide for answers with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [on this thread in the DbFit forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dbfit/P7wNUFM4FU0), your issue can be solved by launching Fitnesse from the unzipped folder:

```
cd <your_dbfit_folder>

./startFitnesse.sh
```